# Limiting functions of the constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, constructor

Please have a look at the following code

**GameObject.cpp**

```
#include "GameObject.h"


GameObject::GameObject(void)
{
    id = 0;
}

GameObject::GameObject(int i)
{
    id = i;
}


GameObject::~GameObject(void)
{
}
```

**GameObject.h**

```
#pragma once
class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject(void);
    GameObject(int);
    ~GameObject(void);


    int id;
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GameObject.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GameObject obj1;
    cout << obj1.id << endl;

    GameObject obj2(45);
    cout << obj2.id << endl;;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to make sure that it is not possible to define an object of the gameObject type using default constructor. How can I do it? Please help!

Comment: Don't define the default constructor?

Comment: or make the default constructor private?

Comment: Or delete it perhaps? I'm all for not defining, but the error messages for doing something with it are a bit nicer.

Comment: @Sepala It is not clear to me at all why you defined the default constructor if you don't want it ever used. Could you clarify this?

Comment: @jogojapan, Just my opinion, but the `void`s in the parameter lists could indicate that the OP is used to C, and not too familiar with C++, causing a misunderstanding that one must always have a default constructor. It's a long shot, but it's possible :p

Comment: is that is the only way?

Comment: Is what the only way? Three options were mentioned so far. They are all valid. Which one is best depends on the rest of your program.

Comment: @Sepala, What's wrong with the three options provided? What exactly are you trying to do that they won't work?

Comment: they do work. I just asked :) Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the default constructor private.

As a sample, usually, when we implement a singleton class, we make the default constructor private and provide a static public "instance" method.

Comment: Thank you Evan. I really appreciate your reply. +1

Comment: I don't think it'd really be used as a singleton if the `int` conversion is still possible.